# NPM Package fails to compile in Clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript, google-closure-compiler, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I am trying to use [uber/react-map-gl](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl) with Clojurescript. I have added it the `project.clj`-

```
:npm-deps {"@cljs-oss/module-deps" "^1.1.1"
           :react-map-gl "^3.3.0-alpha.5"
           :react "^16.4.1"}
```

and `npm install`ed it separately. When I require it from my ns -

```
(:require [react-map-gl :as M 
                        :refer [BaseControl TRANSITION_EVENTS 
                                FlyToInterpolator]])

(js/console.log M)
(js/console.log BaseControl)
(js/console.log M/BaseControl) ;;-> also fails
```

`M` is correctly logged to the console, but drilling into the attributes (such as `BaseControl`) throws an Exception -

```
Exception: ReferenceError: 
...$node_modules$react_map_gl$dist$esm$components$base_control is not defined at Object.get BaseControl [as BaseControl] (http://localhost:3449/js/compiled/out/node_modules/react-map-gl/dist/esm/index.js:5:19) at Object.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)]
```

A handful of the attributes are accessible (e.g. no exceptions), such as `TRANSITION_EVENTS` and `FlyToInterpolator`.

I see [this bug](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-2818) (which may or may not be relevant), but I am not sure how to proceed or even troubleshoot. Here's a [minimal failing example](https://github.com/nrakochy/react-map-gl-failing) to repro. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems this issue is related to the aforementioned bug. The failing example posted there has [some helpful info](https://github.com/au-phiware/cljs-2818#actual-outcome) on what the problem is, though I am not sure how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer (really just a comment).

I was able to ostensibly get farther by first manually requiring all of the components and overlays (which points to some deps mismanagement of some sort).

```
$ clj -m cljs.main -co compile-opts.edn -r
ClojureScript 1.10.339
cljs.user=> (require '"react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/popup"
 '"react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/navigation-control"
 '"react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/interactive-map"
 '"react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/base-control"
 '"react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/static-map"
 '"react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/marker"
 '"react-map-gl/dist/esm/overlays/svg-overlay"
 '"react-map-gl/dist/esm/overlays/html-overlay"
 '"react-map-gl/dist/esm/overlays/canvas-overlay"
 '[react-map-gl :as M
                        :refer [BaseControl TRANSITION_EVENTS
                                FlyToInterpolator]])

cljs.user=> M
#js {:default nil, :InteractiveMap nil, :StaticMap nil, :BaseControl nil, :Marker nil, :Popup nil, :NavigationControl nil, :CanvasOverlay nil, :HTMLOverlay nil, :SVGOverlay nil, :TRANSITION_EVENTS #js {:BREAK 1, :SNAP_TO_END 2, :IGNORE 3}, :TransitionInterpolator #object[TransitionInterpolator], :LinearInterpolator #object[LinearInterpolator], :FlyToInterpolator #object[ViewportFlyToInterpolator], :experimental #js {:MapControls #object[MapControls]}}
```

You can see that, while this avoids the `...$node_modules$react_map_gl$dist$esm$components$base_control is not defined` error, it is not really a solution as things like `:BaseControl` end up being `nil`.

You can get a sense of the dependencies at play by making a revision to the compiler to log the results of calls to `cljs.closure/index-node-modules`.

My `deps.edn`:

```
{:deps {org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version "1.10.339"}}}
```

and `compile-opts.edn`:

```
{:npm-deps {:react-map-gl "^3.3.0-alpha.5"
            :react "^16.4.1"}
 :install-deps true
 :output-dir "out"}
```

Comment: Just now getting back after some time away. I do appreciate the note. 

It is curious to me that requiring the lib as a string works okay (e.g. `'"react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/base-control"` albeit `nil`), but requiring the lib as a symbol fails to compile (e.g. `'[react-map-gl/dist/esm/components/base-control]` throws an exception)

At this point I have decided to start evaluating some other options for Mapbox maps.